# Azure Data Factory Pagination issue

Tags: azure, pagination, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I have a copy activity with Source- Rest API call and sink- Blob storage(JSON) and results are stored in Json. The copy activity loads only first 142 records and doesn't load the next set of records using the AbsoluteUrl Body paging.next.link
Below is a sample result from API response:

```
[
  {

"results": [
      {
        "id": "abc",
        "properties": {
          "createdate": "",
          "domain": "",
          "hs_lastmodifieddate": "",
          "hs_object_id": "",
          "name": "."
        },
        "createdAt": "",
        "updatedAt": "",
        "archived": false
      },
       {
        "id": "xyz",
        "properties": {
          "createdate": "",
          "domain": "",
          "hs_lastmodifieddate": "",
          "hs_object_id": "",
          "name": ""
        },
        "createdAt": "",
        "updatedAt": "",
        "archived": false
      },
      
      "paging": {
      "next": {
        "after": "67545677",
        "link": "https://api.abb.com/crm/v3/objects/aaa?limit=100&after=67545677"
       }
      }
  }
 ]
```

I need to pass the link value to fetch next set of data.

**ADF pagination**:
[image]

Tried using None with $.paging.next.link and still getting first set of records only

Answer (score 0):

I tried with a sample REST API and got expected results in the output JSON file.

[image]

Your REST API sample JSON results an invalid JSON. Make sure you gave the correct next link path in the pagination rules.

If the issue still persists, I suggest you raise the [support request](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/support/create-ticket/).

If you know the total number of pages, then you can try the below approach as a workaround.

- Use the combination of **For Each and copy activity**(JSON will be copied from each page to a JSON file in every iteration) to get individual JSON files.
- After ForEach use another **copy activity with merge option in sink** to merge those files into a single JSON file.

Comment: Rakesh:  Thanks for your reply. I just took a sample from the API response in Dataset(preview data).

Comment: It's invalid because I missed the ] in the JSON. I have edited the response with 'abc', 'xyz',..  to remove the sensitive data                                                                                                                                       
 I tried using AbsoluteUrl  Body paging.next.link  & AbsoluteURl None $.paging.next.link     How can I store the value of copy activity output - paging next link to a variable?

Comment: Use web activity to get that. Store it in a variable. Make an array of length of total number of pages and give it to Foreach. First time store the URL in a variable before forEach. Use this variable in copy activity source URL. Update the next link in the variable in every iteration after copy activity using web activity.

Comment: I almost there in resolving the issue. I dont have the total number of pages info. I have stored the paging next link value in a variable. How do I use it in Foreach with copy data activity

Comment: In ForEach, you need to give an array of length of total number of pages. First, before ForEach, store the link in a variable. Inside ForEach, give the url stored in variable to copy activity. This will be copied to temp location. Then use a web activity with the variable. Using the result of the web activity, update the variable with the next link. This will repeat until the last page. But this method needs the total number of pages.